# Regex to reduce the spaces in a file by 1

Tags: regex

I've a file and I want to make the following changes in it:

Replace `n` consecutive spaces by `n-1` spaces.

Example:

Input:

```
a b  c   e
fg j    ij k
```

Output:

```
ab c  e
fgj   ijk
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in `sed` as:

```
sed  -r -i 's/ ( *)/\1/g' in
```

The regex used `/ ( *)/` searches for a space followed by zero or more spaces. It remembers the zero or more spaces part and replaces the entire spaces by the remembered part.

Answer (score 7):

`s/ ( *)/$1/g`

That is, replace a space followed by any number (including 0) of spaces, with the latter number of spaces. In essence, we're matching `/ +/` while capturing `/ */`.